# List of weighted pairs based on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
doc type    thing
3   A   pig
4   B   horse
4   C   cat
4   D   pig
5   C   horse
5   A   bird
5   B   cat
```

I want a new dataframe with three columns (thing; thing; times) populated by all pairs of 'things' that have ever appeared in the same 'doc', and in how many docs. Based on the dataframe above, the desired output would be:

```
thing   thing   times
horse   cat     2
horse   pig     1
cat pig         1
horse   bird    1
bird    cat     1
```

I achieved something along these lines with itertools, outside of pandas, but how can this be done with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df_filtered = df[['doc', 'thing']]
pd.merge(df_filtered, df_filtered, on='doc')
    .query("thing_x < thing_y")
    .groupby(by=['thing_x', 'thing_y'])
    .agg({'doc': 'nunique'})
    .reset_index()
```

First of all, you can use [`pandas.merge()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to produce the Cartesian product of all the rows which have the same document, excluding duplicate entries with the reversed order, and entries in which thing_x == thing_y.
In this way you get a table like this:

```
    doc thing_x thing_y
5   4   horse   pig
6   4   cat     horse
8   4   cat     horse
10  4   cat     pig
15  4   horse   pig
16  4   cat     horse
18  4   cat     horse
20  4   cat     pig
29  5   bird    horse
31  5   bird    cat
32  5   cat     horse
```

Then you [`.groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the couple of `thing`s, count the number of distinct documents for each group, and call [`.reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to flatten the hierarchical grouping.

Final result:

```
    thing_x thing_y doc
0   bird    cat     1
1   bird    horse   1
2   cat     horse   2
3   cat     pig     1
4   horse   pig     1
```

Comment: A good suggestion. What do the numbers in the 'doc' column actually say in your final result?

Comment: For each couple of things, the number is how many times that couple of items has appeared in the same document.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. I realise that one could add code to remove lines where thing_x == thing_y. Is there also an easy way to count lines such as `horse; cat` and `cat; horse` only once so that direction (x-y, y-x) does not matter?

Comment: I've edited my answer. First of all I realized that you wanted the number of distinct documents in which the couple appeared together, not the number of times they did in the same document. And I removed thing_x == thing_y entries and fixed the direction issue.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Just out of interest, what really does `.query("thing_x < thing_y")` do, when "<" is applied to strings not numbers?

Comment: The strings are compared with [lexicographical ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types).